# MongoDB Aggregation: How to return only the values that don't exist in all documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Lets say I have an array `['123', '456', '789']`

I want to Aggregate and look through every document with the field `books` and only return the values that are NOT in any documents. For example if '123' is in a document, and '456' is, but '789' is not, it would return an array with ['789'] as it's not included in any `books` fields in any document.

```
.aggregate( [
{
  $match: {
    books: {
        $in: ['123', '456', '789']
    }
  }
},
```

I don't want the documents returned, but just the actual values that are not in any documents.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to scan the entire collection to look for missing book values.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {  // "explode" books array to docs with individual book values
    "$unwind": "$books"
  },
  {  // scan entire collection creating set of book values
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "allBooksSet": {
        "$addToSet": "$books"  // <-- generate set of book values
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,  // don't need this anymore
      "missing": {  // use $setDifference to find missing values
        "$setDifference": [
          [ "123", "456", "789" ],  // <-- your values go here
          "$allBooksSet"  // <-- the entire collection's set of book values
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "missing": [ "789" ]
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z1YYKCId-3b).

Answer (score 1):

Based on @rickhg12hs's answer, there is another variation replacing `$unwind` with `$reduce`, which considered less costly. Two out of Three steps are the same:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      allBooks: {$push: "$books"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      allBooksSet: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$allBooks",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$setUnion: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      missing: {
        $setDifference: [["123","456", "789"], "$allBooksSet"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V7Yywewgdv7).

Comment: I read your answer and thought, yeah @nimrod-serok is right, I wonder how much slower my answer's pipeline is.  I created a collection on MongoDB Atlas based on `sample_training.grades` that had 10000 documents.  I then ran `.explain("executionStats")` on both of our pipelines and I was surprised that mine was faster.  Due to server load, I suppose, there was some variability in `.executionStats.executionTimeMillis`, but my pipeline was consistently faster.  I think I understand some factors that might influence this, but certainly not all.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps the difference is how the server optimizes.  E.g., what I `"$unwind"`/"explode" into more docs, you `"$push"`/"cram" into a single field ... and the server is better at processing more docs versus processing a single field's large value?  Both methods have great opportunity for parallelization, but the server is better at one method versus another?

Comment: I don't understand all the internals, thus I don't 'a-priori' think one answer is better than the other, I just know `$unwind` is considered to be a slow process most of the times. For cases where optimization is important, the best approach is to check several strategies and see which one is better for the specific case - as you did.